# A question on the product of element orders of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and $\psi(G)$ be the sum of element orders of $G$. Then $\psi(G)\leq\psi(C_n)$, where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$ (see "Sums of element orders in finite groups", Comm. Algebra 37 (2009), 2978-2980). Is it true a similar inequality for the product of element orders of $G$?

Comment: Have you checked it for small examples? I personally have no intuition otherwise for why this should/should not be true...

Comment: Yes, it seems to be true.

Comment: The sum of elements theorem was proved in 1991 - earlier than the 2009 paper cited here. **Citation:** Schmidt, F., Stong, R., & Lindsey, J. H. (1991). 6636. *American Mathematical Monthly*, 970-972.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Denoting the order of $g$ by $o(g)$, you can show that for any decreasing function $f$ the following inequality holds
$$\sum_{g\in G}f(o(g))\geq \sum_{g\in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z}f(o(g)).$$
This is because one can actually construct a bijection $\sigma:G\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ which satisfies $$o(\sigma(g))\geq o(g)$$ for all $g\in G$. The main ingredient is a classical [theorem of Frobenius](http://www.pitt.edu/~gmc/ch1/node7.html) saying that when $k$ divides the order of a group, the number of elements of order dividing $k$ is divisible by $k$, then proceed by induction. An application of this exact idea is for example [problem 10775](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2695368) on the American Math Monthly. For your question we just need $f(x)=-\log x$.

Comment: It's an interesting idea. I will try to give a complete proof. Thanks!

Comment: The proof given in that Monthly solution seems to me to be at best
incomplete. I agree (in the notation of that problem) that the
sets S_d for divisors d of k do not consume too much of the set G_k,
but what about sets S_d where d < k but d is not a divisor. Perhaps
they involve some elements of G_k. Does anyone see a way to repair
this problem?

Comment: The proof seems to only want to define $S_d$ for $d \le n$ with $d$ a divisor of $n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Aaron: The problem is with the $S_d$ with $d < k$, $d$ not a divisor of $k$, but $\gcd(d,k) \neq 1$. Those $S_d$'s might have taken away too many elements of $G_k$, leaving less than $\phi(k)$ elements to build $S_k$.