# Check rapidly if a map of finite groups is a homomorphism

Tags: finite-groups, algorithms

I have two non-abelian finite groups $G$ and $H$ of equal size $n$ and a map $f$ from the underlying set of $G$ to the underlying set of $H$. I store the groups as their multiplication tables (i.e. the elements have been ordered and I store an nxn table of integers). In particular a minimal presentation is not known (though maybe it can be cheaply computed).

What is computationally the cheapest way to check if $f$ defines a homomorphism? We can do it in O(n^2) obviously. Does the assumption that $f$ is a bijection help?

Comment: Here's a way to do this in $O(n\log n)$ operations: Inductively find a generating set $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ for $G$ where $k\leq\log_2n$ (as in my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/338162/95685). Then you just need to check that $f(g_ih)=f(g_i)f(h)$ for all $h\in G$ and each $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.