# The Average of Orders 

Tags: gr.group-theory

Among all groups $G$ of order $n$ which one will maximum the value: $\frac 1n\sum_{g \in G}O(g)$ ? (Where $o(g)$ is the order of $g$).

Comment: For generalisation of this question and further information around it see also this MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104183/order-increasing-bijection-from-arbitrary-groups-to-cyclic-groups  Yet the situation regarding the generalistation seems a bit inconclusive. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As quid has stated the maximum attained for $\mathbb{Z}_n$. The problem goes back to 1991. See Americam Mathematical Monthly 1991, page 970.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum is attained for the cycylic group of order $n$, and only for this this group.

See [Sums of element orders in finite groups](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an%3A1183.20022&format=complete) Commincations in Algebra, Vol 37, 2009,  which considers this problem (except for not dividing by $n$, which however changes nothing, since in the question the order of the group is fixed).

(The link is to the Zentralblatt MATH review and should work without subscription.)